# Cross Date Picker issue default value should be blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

Hello all i am using cross date picker from github 
the code is like this

```
 <?php 
            $date = date("j",strtotime($details['founded'])); // date fetched
            $month = date("n",strtotime($details['founded']));
            $year = date("Y",strtotime($details['founded']));        
                    ?>
```

HTML

```
  <input type="date" data-initial-day="<?=$date?>" data-initial-year="<?=$year?>" data-initial-month="<?=$month?>" class='TEx_About_allihh' name="estdate" required/>
```

JS

```
<script>  $("input[type='date']").cdp();</script>


the src of github is https://github.com/lcnvdl/cross-datepicker
```

Everything is working good when there is a value in the php date, month and year variables but when they are blank i want them to show default values like day,month,year

right now it shows blank or 1.

and also some times i want them not to have any values.

if you have any idea how to achieve this please let me know i have also asked a question on github but got no response

Comment: In order to make my answer more complete: It is atm not clear what the default should be, I read: "default value should be blank", "i want them to show default values like day,month,year" and "and also some times i want them not to have any values"

Answer (score 0):

using the `null coalescing operator` that would be

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary

```
$temp = (date("j",strtotime($details['founded'])); //try to convert array element to time
if ($details['founded'] != "") { //check if it isn't an empty string
    $date = $temp ?? strtotime("now"); //set it to the converted time or set it to the current time
} else {
strtotime("now"); //fallback for an empty string
```

}

Comment: sorry for the late reply but what i want is to show the default values of textboxes as day, month and year . right now it is blank if no value is there in the php variables

Comment: @sonamSharma with this code you create a default PHP variable for `$date` if it is empty it will set to default. I can improve it now

Comment: i think something needs to be done with the plugin not with php as if i dont have anything in the php variables then the values of date month and year fields are blank i want them to show as "Select Day" "Select Month" And "Select Year"

Comment: Doesn't really matter where, but also possible

Answer (score 0):

Go through my given link and use one of them date picker, i hope you will not get this kind of error:

[Date Picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples)